# I can't format with comma in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I use eclipse for java programming. I want to compile `10999.9999` to 11,000.00. Here is the code I wrote:

```
String x = "10999.9999";
double y = Double.parseDouble(x);
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00");
System.out.println(formatter.format(y));
```

then it gives output  11000.00, no comma. I compiled the code with cmd and it works perfectly. So I believe there is something wrong in my eclipse or may be i need to turn on some settings.

*Also to mention: My Eclipse never compiles comma*

[The Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fR0zX.png) [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxBq0.png)

Comment: If you're getting a different result when compiling from the command line, I suspect that maybe eclipse and javac are not using the same JDKs.

Comment: @ArnabDatta How can i suspect that.

Comment: Because eclipse is just an IDE. It does not compile your code. It can however, be installed with a JDK that compiles your code and that JDK might be different from the one that you are using when you compile via command line.

Comment: @ArnabDatta i have checked it's not for that i am using jdk1.8.0_05

Comment: replace  DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00"); from this DecimalFormat formatter2 = new DecimalFormat(",###.00");

Comment: Have you tried adding a locale to the formatter, e.g. `DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH)`?

Comment: @tobias_k yes I believe, I tried almost every option.

Answer (score 2):

```
String x = "10999.9999";
double y = Double.parseDouble(x);
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("###,###.00");
System.out.println(formatter.format(y));
```

will output

```
11.000,00
```

[CHECK IDEONE DEMO HERE](http://ideone.com/vxb9uS)

Comment: @Gonzalez this solution worked for you? If you have further issues don't hesitate to ask

Comment: If this worked, then OPs original code should have worked, too. The problem is probably somewhere else. Also, should add `Locale.ENGLISH` to get the right output.

Comment: @JordiCastilla no it didn't. I think the problem is in eclipse not in the code. But thank you.